# Javascript: Soundmanager2 and Soundcloud event callback

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I'm trying to build my own soundcloud media player, using the options provided by both SoundManager2 and Soundcloud.

Here is my current code:

```
SC.stream('/tracks/' + this.media.mediaId, function(audio){
            audio.load({
                onload : function(){
                    var duration = this.duration;

                },
                onfinish : function(){
                    self.updatePlayButton();
                    console.log('Finished');
                },
                onresume : function(){
                    self.updatePlayButton();
                    console.log("resumed");
                },
                onstop : function(){
                    self.updatePlayButton();
                    console.log("Stopped");
                },
                onpause : function() {
                    self.updatePlayButton();
                    console.log('Paused');
                },
                whileplaying : function()
                {
                    console.log(this.position);
                    self.updateScrubber(this.position / (this.duration / 100));
                    self.$timeLeft.text(self.formatTime(this.position / 1000));
                    console.log(totalPercent,'My position');
                }

            });
            self.audio = audio.sID;
            self.registerEvents();
        });
```

I play the audio using:

```
soundManager.getSoundById(self.audio).togglePause();
```

The audio play's, and all the callbacks are fired accordingly. But after the "onfinish" callback, when I hit play again it will replay the audio, but it wont fire any of the events.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for [`SC.stream()`](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#stream) the "options" object can be passed in as the second argument:

**`SC.stream(trackPath, [options], [callback])`**

The options will be associated with the `soundObject` itself, so you won't need to declare them again when calling individual methods such as `.load()` and `.play()`

Try making the call like this:

```
var myOptions = {
  onload : function() {
    var duration = this.duration;
  },
  onfinish : function(){
    self.updatePlayButton();
    console.log('Finished');
  },
  onresume : function(){
    self.updatePlayButton();
    console.log("resumed");
  },
  onstop : function(){
    self.updatePlayButton();
    console.log("Stopped");
  },
  onpause : function() {
    self.updatePlayButton();
    console.log('Paused');
  },
  whileplaying : function() {
    console.log(this.position);
    self.updateScrubber(this.position / (this.duration / 100));
    self.$timeLeft.text(self.formatTime(this.position / 1000));
    console.log(totalPercent,'My position');
  }
}

SC.stream('/tracks/' + this.media.mediaId, myOptions, function(audio){
  audio.load();
  self.audio = audio.sID;
  self.registerEvents();
});
```

There are some other strange-looking things about your code, such as not doing anything with the variable `duration` inside the `onload` function. Also, using a variable `self` while also using `this` ends up looking like you're not sure if you're writing Python or JavaScript, but maybe it makes sense to you.

Hopefully attaching the options to the `soundObject` this way will solve your immediate problem anyhow. Good luck!

Comment: Just to be clear, it looks like @menzo-wijmenga is using the relatively common `var self = this` design pattern. The controller may have methods like `updatePlayButton` and `updateTimeLeft` while accessing the audio option's `duration` or `position` attribute via event binding (i.e. `self` refers to the controller that is calling the stream, whereas `this` refers to the audio object).